# Django - super(ModelForm, self).clean() without raising ValidationError

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to implement a special trick in my validation. I want the program to raise a ValidationError only when two fields are both invalid. One is a field for email, thus being an emailField in the model. The other one is for phone number and is a CharField in the model.

**models.py**

```
...
email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
telephone = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
...
```

In forms.py I am using the built-in clean for email and building a custom one for phone numbers.

**forms.py**

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data=super(ContactInstructorForm, self).clean()

    try:
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    except:
        email = False

    telephone = self.cleaned_data['telephone']

    mobile_regex = r'^(\+46|0|\(\+46\)) *(7[0236])( |-|)(\d{4} \d{3}|\d{3} \d{4}|\d{3} \d{2} \d{2}|\d{2} \d{2} \d{3}|\d{7})$'
    home_phone_regex = r'^(\+46|0|\(\+46\)) *(8)( |-|)(\d{4} \d{2}|\d{2} \d{4}|\d{3} \d{3}|\d{2} \d{2} \d{2}|\d{6})$'
    if not re.match(mobile_regex, telephone) and not re.match(home_phone_regex, telephone):
        telephone = False

    if not email and not telephone:
        raise ValidationError()
```

However, the problem is that the built-in clean() method not only returns a dictionary of all validated fields and their values. But upon failure also automatically raises an ValidationError.

*This causes my program to fail when only the inputted email is invalid (even though the phone number is fine)* **This behaviour is unwanted!**

So ultimately I am asking what the best way to build around the built-in validation for email (especially when the phone number is valid), but at the same time use the build-in validation (especially when the phone number is invalid) and for all the other fields.

**Update:**
I am also using an automated honeypot from the module "djangospam". This is included in the template, just before the form.

```
{% include 'djangospam/form.html' %}
```

Which translates to in HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.somewebsite.com">
    <label for="honeypot">Honeypot</label>
    <input id="honeypot" type="text" name="honeypot"></input>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name"></input>
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email"></input>
    <label for="url">Website (optional)</label>
    <input id="url" type="text" name="url"></input>
    <label for="comment">Your comment</label>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='8Nwq32Mbh6KA1h3C1U4ZMRe2nTkUGSbebVgsQbF8zZL2dKoZAS4kjoQM8W1NEb3g' />
    <input type="submit" value="Send"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your email is always being set with `email = self.cleaned_data['email']` that is it is always `True`. It never runs into the except block. This coupled with the last condition sets it to raise the `Validation error`. Put your email regex like you did with telephone and you should be fine.

Edit:- Something like this

```
email = self.cleaned_data['email']
telephone = self.cleaned_data['telephone']

email_regex--- your email_regex/validation here
```

Comment: Removing the try-except block and putting telephone and email side by side like this:

email = self.cleaned_data['email']
telephone = self.cleaned_data['telephone']

Causes the application to crash with a KeyError whenever the email is invalid.

Comment: Updated comment

Comment: Is this the only place where you are doing your cleans? Where else are you doing them?

Comment: I am doing two other cleans in this Form Class. clean_first_name(self) and clean_honeypot(self)

Comment: I did a small update on what I think could cause this solution to not work. It is marked as "Update" in the original question.